# Comandos do WEBPACK não funcionam

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle

instalei o webpack com o comando `npm install webpack -g` , porem quando tento usar o comando o `webpack -h` ou outro qualquer da esse problema

```
> PS C:\Users\renan\Desktop\Wchat> webpack -h The CLI moved into a
> separate package: webpack-cli Would you like to install webpack-cli?
> (That will run npm install -D webpack-cli) (yes/NO)
```

Apos da yes , aparece o seguinte erro

```
PS C:\Users\renan\Desktop\Wchat> webpack -h
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
Would you like to install webpack-cli? (That will run npm install -D webpack-cli) (yes/NO)yes
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-prese
t-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!
npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm WARN Wchat@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN Wchat@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ webpack-cli@2.1.2
updated 1 package in 45.313s
{ Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at runCommand.then.result (C:\Users\renan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:62:14)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Com esse erro fico inutilizado de usar os comando `webpack` , Alguem poderia me ajudar a resolver  ?

Aqui esta o `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "trabalhofinal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.5.9",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "simple-peer": "^9.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Apos ajeitar o comando webpack apareceu o seguinte erro ao tentar fazer um bundle.js

```
webpack ./src/app.js ./public/bundle.js
Hash: 0ad17ada6fbd759751dd
Version: webpack 4.6.0
Time: 629ms
Built at: 2018-05-01 01:45:09
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] ./src/app.js 23 bytes {0} [built]
[1] multi ./src/app.js ./public/bundle.js 40 bytes {0} [built]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

ERROR in multi ./src/app.js ./public/bundle.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './public/bundle.js' in 'C:\Users\renan\Desktop\TrabalhoFinal'
 @ multi ./src/app.js ./public/bundle.js
PS C:\Users\renan\Desktop\TrabalhoFinal>
```

Comment: Bom, até aonde consta, ele foi instalado. [**Edite**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/295330/edit) sua pergunta e coloque o conteúdo do arquivo **package.json** .. Se não me engano, para instalar um pacote global, usa-se o comando `npm install -g pacote` e não `npm install pacote -g` pode ser ai aonde esta o problema

Comment: Editei e botei o packge.json amigo !

Comment: Tente remover ele: `npm uninstall -g webpack-cli` e instalar novamente: `npm install -g webpack-cli`

Comment: Amigo funcionou , porem apareceu outro problema ja editei a pergunta e botei ele, vc poderia dar uma olhada ?

Comment: Você deve abrir outra pergunta, pois trata-se de outro projeto, pois percebesse pelo diretório **C:\Users\renan\Desktop\TrabalhoFinal**

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda NoobSaibot , muito obrigado mesmo , esta tudo funcionando !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erro pode ter sido causado devido a ordem do argumento `-g` no comando, que segundo a [documentação](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally) é:

```
npm install -g webpack-cli
```

diferente do Yarn que é:

```
yarn add webpack-cli -g
```

#### Referência

- [How to Install Global Packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally)